# Chinese idiom puzzle 9 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

Please solve the puzzle below

[image]

Hints:

1. Use the power of others to dominate
2. Like bathing in the spring breeze
3. Rock breaking shock the sky
4. It's like disappearing all at once
5. A very long distance
6. Earthmoving, mountains shaking
7. An unfair treaty signed under the threat of force
8. Describe the peril and suffering of the people
9. Swear in the name of heaven and the sun
10. Come and go as will
11. burn books and bury scholars
12. Counterfeiting
13. Albatross
14. Useless person
15. Offense one's superior
16. accompany the sovereign is like accompanying a tiger
17. When seeing a virtuous man, can't help but want to imitate
18. Lest all under heaven are not in chaos and disorder,
    (motivated by a desire to see the world in chaos)
19. Arrogantly overestimate oneself
20. Continuously Day and night
21. Selectively blessed by Heaven
22. In a hurry, can't wait
23. Sing the praises of someone

A. Mutual destruction

B. Unexpected disaster

C. Like a fish in the water

D. The sky collapse, the earth crack

E. One of the 戰國四公子

F. Only I on top (Describes people who are arrogant and look down on others)

G. Like the sun at noon (at the highest point of prosperity)

H. Describe a deserted place with harsh natural conditions

I. Once riding on the back of a tiger, it is dangerous to get off (a metaphor for facing a dilemma)

J. Play with fire and get burned

K. Not too fast, not too slow (study pace)

L. Describe one's air of magnificence and awesomeness

M. 俠以武作亂 (originally 俠以武犯禁)

N. 儒以文犯法 (originally 儒以文亂法)

O. Expecting to be soon

P. The entire country is in turmoil

Q. Oath between two lovers

R. Clear insights

S. Party every night

T. Wind is cool, water is cold (cool and comfortable)

U. Feeling or mentally poor and not thinking about food.

V. The self-proclaimed title of 孫悟空

Comment: [20 sound strange to me](https://old.pep.com.cn/xiaoyu/jiaoshi/study/jszy/yy/bzxc/201012/t20101202_981054.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in simplified Chinese. And agree with **tsh**.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I have  山長水遠 for #5, But 山高水遠 seems to be an acceptable variant

Comment: 日以繼夜: https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E6%97%A5%E4%BB%A5%E7%B9%BC%E5%A4%9C

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the Puzzle

> [image]

*In case someone didn't know, I created all the puzzles I posted here to challenge other users, not seeking the answers I don't know.*